# Insertion Sort Problems

Tags: c++

I'm doing an insertion sort for my introductory C++ class, and it seems to be working, but I keep getting repeats in my sorted list.

In main

```
Storage s;
for (int i = 0; i < 20000; ++i)
{
    cout << "adding " << iss[i] << " to sorted list" << endl;
    s.Add(iss[i]);
}
```

and in Storage.cpp

```
    void Storage::Add(int num)
{
    it = mylist.begin();
    if (mylist.empty())
    {
        Node tem(num);
        mylist.push_front(tem);
    }
    else 
    {
        while (it != mylist.end())
        {
            if (num < (*it).GetNumber())
            {
                Node temp(num);
                mylist.insert(it, temp);
            }
            it++;
            if (it == mylist.end())
            {
                Node te(num);
                mylist.push_back(te);
            }
        }
    }
    it = mylist.begin();
    while (it != mylist.end())
    {
        cout << (*it).GetNumber() << ',';
        it++;
    }
    cout << endl << mylist.size() <<endl;
}
```

`Node` just stores the number that is being added to the list as well as the time, which is calculated inside `Node`.

I can't figure out why I'm getting repeats, thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Try stepping through the code and watch what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your while loop.

```
    while (it != mylist.end())  // Here
    {
        if (num < (*it).GetNumber()) // Here
        {
            Node temp(num);
            mylist.insert(it, temp); // and here
        }
        it++;
        if (it == mylist.end())
        {
            Node te(num);
            mylist.push_back(te); // And here
        }
```

Have you learned about break yet?  You keep going through the loop after you add it, and add it at the end, too.

Comment: Just saw that myself, been looking at that same code all day, can't believe I missed that!

Comment: @Wajahat Yes you did, at the same time I was composing an answer that said it more clearly.  It would be nice if one of our answers gets accepted, wouldn't it?  And maybe both get upvoted?

Answer (score 1):

In second if condition of your while loop, you always add a new node at the end of the list that is causing repeats.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in this loop

```
    while (it != mylist.end())
    {
        if (num < (*it).GetNumber())
        {
            Node temp(num);
            mylist.insert(it, temp);
        }
        it++;
        if (it == mylist.end())
        {
            Node te(num);
            mylist.push_back(te);
        }
    }
```

If the list has one element then after it++ the iterator will be equal to end() and you will add a new element. After that the current iterator end becames invalid.
I would rewrite it the following way

```
    while ( it != mylist.end() && !( num < (*it).GetNumber() ) ) it++;
    Node temp( num );
    if (it == mylist.end()) mylist.push_back(temp);
    else mylist.insert(it, temp);
```